# How to center button overlaying image with React Bootstrap?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a button overlaying an image, but I can't get it centered in the image. Similar questions seem to point to `text-align: center` but that doesn't work for me...

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-leakey-qz8pn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use flex to make items center i.e

```
  {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-item:center
  }
```

CodeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-dijkstra-vzeb3

Comment: What's the difference here between `justify-content: center;` and `align-items:center`? I see in your CodeSandbox you just used `justify-content: center` and that was sufficient.

Comment: align items align items vertically which in this we dont require while justify content align item horizontally which in this case we does not required.